# easepick prevent selected date in element

Tags: calendar

I'm using inline easepick, when I select a date, it automatically fill the element with selected date! I need to prevent this and work with selected date somewhere else with picker.on('select')

```
<script>
    const picker = new easepick.create({
        element: "#calendar",
        css: [
            "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.css"
        ],
        zIndex: 10,
        inline: true,
        plugins: [
            "LockPlugin"
        ],
        LockPlugin: {
            minDate: new Date(),
        },
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
        //grid: 3,
        //calendars: 2
        setup(picker) {
            picker.on('select', (e) => {

                const {
                    view,
                    date,
                    target
                } = e.detail;
                //console.log(date);
                const startDate = picker.getDate();

                console.log(startDate);
                // do something
            });
        },
    });
</script>
```